# Custom filter to search criteria. Magento 2

Tags: magento, search, filter, criteria

I need to add range filter for year. I redefine the Magento class in my module FullText\Collection. I also made changes in search_request.xml file. I found the code and it works for me:

$skus = [
            'CNS334',
            'U012840'
        ];

```
    $this->filterBuilder->setField('sku');
    $this->filterBuilder->setValue($skus);
    $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType('in');

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
```

But I have data in the another tables. I try to join, but I cant get any results for my filtering.

```
   $this->getSelect()->join(
        [
            'my' => 'make_year',
        ],
        'e.entity_id = my.product_id'

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('year')
        ->setValue(2014)
        ->setConditionType('from')
        ->create());

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('year')
        ->setValue(2015)
        ->setConditionType('to')
        ->create());

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
```

Answer (score 0):

To join your query with other tables you need criteria mapper.

As an example please look at [\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item\StockItemCriteria::setStockStatus()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Item/StockItemCriteria.php#L29) - here is initiated the filter.

Setting new item in `data` array triggers mapper method [\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item\StockItemCriteriaMapper::mapStockStatus()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Item/StockItemCriteriaMapper.php#L125).

This mapper contains `\Magento\Framework\DB\Select` with which we are able to work like in old-style collection.
The name of mapper method correlates with criteria's `data` array index. So if you add `$this->data['custom_field']` the mapper function should be `mapCustomField()`.

Please also note that if there is specific mapper function for the field the mapper will try to filter by [mapped fields](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Item/StockItemCriteriaMapper.php#L62).

Comment: Dead github links